# Phalcon crashes after model operation

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I have a problem with Phalcon framework. When I am trying to do any model's operation my application is crashing.

For example when I am doing something like:

```
class IndexController extends BaseController {
    public function indexAction() {
        //$this->view->t = $this->getTranslation();
        Users::find();
    }
}
```

I am getting a html response with header like

```
Request URL: http://xxxxxx.com
Request Method:GET
Status Code:42000 test
Remote Address:149.202.61.xxx
```

In mysql logs i can find request for data

```
event_time | user_host | thread_id | server_id | command_type | argument  
2015-12-25 00:46:35 | root[root] @ localhost []| 49 | 0 | Query | SELECT  FROM `users`
```

so obviously connection between phalcon and mysql is reached.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any PHP errors?

Comment: Make sure your `Users` class has a property defined for each column in your database. And that the class and method exist: `echo function_exists('Users::find')?'Y':'N';`
Double check your model class names, files names, and table names agree with each other. For example: file: `AuthLogins.php` class: `AuthLogins` table: `auth_logins`. Make sure your models are extending `\Phalcon\Mvc\Model`. And finally, check your `error_log`. You'd be surprised how useful the error_log can be when you're totally stumped.

Comment: Above problem occurs because of error on model. More info you can find here:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471840/

Comment: these problems are combined