# Phalcon pdo excpetion model first

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phalcon

I have problem with phalcon framework namely with models methods...

As you know models has included methods **find()** and **findFirst()**

I have generated model with phalcon-dev tools and now I am trying to do Model::find on it but I am getting an exception but dont know why...

There is some more informations (e.g stacktrace) :

http://exception.mateuszmarzecki.pl/

Comment: Try using `public static function find($parameters = array())` instead of `public static function find($parameters = null)` for your default parameters.

Comment: I've changed default parameter to an array but it doesn't help as you can see on above link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try change methods in model file

```
public static function find($parameters = array())
{
    return self::find($parameters);
}
```

Comment: @Ultimater say the same thing in comment under first post. I've tried it (you can check it on http://extension.mateuszmarzecki.pl) but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does not look like your passing it the right parms.

```
SELECT FROM `nacionality`
```

Notice that your not selecting any fields from the database, and that is why your getting the Exception.

Comment: ya its looks like but its build in method I haven't modify anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

So... after some time of debugging I've found the problem...

For the next generation... if you don't want to lose a week as I did. Just read carefully your application config.

Problems occurs because I missed table and column annotations as well.

In my application config I have something like:

```
$metaData->setStrategy(new \Engine\Db\Model\Annotations\Metadata());
```

so Phalcon was looking for annotations in my model files, more info about this you can find there:

https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1933/column-types-for-model-annotations

Happy New Year